# Can't find space exploration on http://stackexchange.com/sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

We're in public beta now.

Why can't I find space on http://stackexchange.com/sites ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am mistaken, that list is not real time. It is updated only periodically (my guess is daily). So if this site hasn't been added within a day or so, ping me here.

Comment: aaaaaaand now it is there. Good call on daily update